# Adding fade/animate for <Button> in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I've created an authorization component that checks the local AD username/password before accepting new changes made to a form. After the user clicks "authenticate", the function takes a few seconds to run before verifying the user. Since the button doesn't animate or fade away, a user can click it multiple times causing an issue.

I'm trying to implement a simple fade/animate to this button, but having a difficult time implementing some suggestions. If you have any tips on how to implement or what React addon to look into, it would be much appreciated.

```
                 <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={() => props.onClose(ConfirmationDialogButtons.CANCEL)} color="primary">
                        Cancel
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={handleSign} color="primary">
                        Authenticate
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>
```

Here is the onClick={handleSign} code.

```
const handleSign = async () => {
        const srv = new DataServer()
        const result = await srv.eSignature(formData.userId, formData.password, props.securityArea, props.prompt, formData.comment)
        if(result.error === 0) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("Authenticated" , JSON.stringify({Authenticated : true , time : new Date()}))
            props.onClose(ConfirmationDialogButtons.OK)
        }
        else {
            setSignError(result.error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a component library like material ui which would auto fade your buttons for you

Comment: Will take a look at that now. Thank you

Comment: Ended up using the disabled feature in a button to disable the button from being clicked after the first click. disabled={isAuthenticating}